# What is the maximum number of "Authorized JavaScript Origins"?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-client

This question is simple and to the point: What is the maximum number of "Authorized Javascript Origins" you can enter?

Upon researching to see if there is a max, I have seen articles from Google stating that G Suite only allows for 50 domains to be whitelisted. However, this is the Developer Console for Google APIs (not equivalent to G Suite). Nonetheless, after just entering 50 or more origin entries, I was not prompted stating "You have reached the maximum number of entries".

Thanks to all that reply.

Comment: I have never heard of there being one but for the fun of it am going to check with someone at google

Comment: Thank you DaImTo!